# Get reference to parent document from embedded document in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

I'd like to have access to the parent object from an embedded object, but can't find a way to do it. I'll show here an example of what this means:

I have 2 Java classses like this:

```
@Document    
public class Parent {
  private String name;
  private List<Child> children;

  @PersistenceConstructor
  public Parent (String name, List<Child> children) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = children;
  }

...

@Document
public class Child {
  private String name;
  private Parent parent;

  @PersistenceConstructor
  public Child(String name, Parent parent) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  ...
```

My document in MongoDB is like this:

```
{
  "name": "some name",
  "children" : {
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name2"
  }
}
```

Is it somehow possible to get reference to the parent, for example in the constructor in Child class? It seems that all the parameters in @PersistenceConstructor annotated constructor in Child class have to come from the children array, which means that the parameter named parent comes as null :(

I know that if I create my own Converter implementation, I could just de-serialize Parent and Child and set the parent reference to child myself, but my actual document is quite big and having to write the de-serialization code myself would be a lot of boiler-plate code.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to set the parent reference manually:

in Child:

```
@Transient
private Parent parent;

public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

The @Transient annotation tells spring data to ignore the field when saving the object.

Then in Parent:

```
@PersistenceConstructor
public Parent (String name, List<Child> children) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = children;
    for (Child child : children) {
        child.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

and with some clever interfaces and helper class or inheritance the amount of duplicated code will be minimal.

Comment: Yes, this is one way to do it, thanks for pointing that out! I'm still in a search for a solution that would allow me to keep the Child object immutable and require it to have a parent always. For that, I probably just have to go with the converter way.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant of @František Hartman's answer, instead of using `@PersistenceConstructor` you can use a `AfterConvertCallback` to populate the `parent` field, so that the inner working remains mostly invisible to the entity class.

This is the callback:

```
@Configuration
public class EntityCallbacks {

    @Bean
    AfterConvertCallback<MyDocument> myDocumentAfterConvertCallback() {
        return (entity, document, collection) -> {
            entity.getChild().setParent(entity);
            return entity;
        };
    }

}
```

And these are your entity classes (I also used Lombok):

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "myCollection")
public class MyDocument {  
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field("field")
    private String field;
    @Field("child")
    private MyChildDocument child;
}

@Data
//the following annotations are necessary to avoid a stack overflow when calling the corresponding methods
@ToString(exclude = "parent")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "parent")
public static class MyChildDocument {
    @Transient
    private MyDocument parent;
    @Field("childField")
    private String childField;
}
```